# trigger not updating sql

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Although this is completed successfully on completion, it is not having the desired update.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger1
On dbo.[table1] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
Declare @Id int;
SELECT @Id = Issue_Id FROM dbo.[table1]

INSERT INTO dbo.[storage]
    SELECT Id, Title, project, Problem
    FROM dbo.[table2]
    WHERE Id = @Id
```

Is there something I am doing wrong or that I can't use variables within the scope of a trigger?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The others have correctly answered that you should be using `inserted` and a join, to build a proper trigger. But:

Based on your comments to other's answers - you should never attempt to access any resource outside of your own database from a trigger, let along from another server.

Try to decouple the trigger activity from the cross server activity - say have your trigger add a row to a queue table (or use real service broker queues), and have an independent component be responsible for servicing these requests.

Otherwise, if there are any e.g. network issues, not only does your trigger break, but it forces a rollback for the original update also - it makes your local database unusable.

This also means that the independent component can cope with timeouts, and perform appropriate retries, etc.

Comment: Yes, not the most ideal of situations. Thanks very much for your additional input concerning the problems I could encounter.

Answer (score 4):

To support multirow updates

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger1 On dbo.[table1] FOR UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO dbo.[storage]
    SELECT t.Id, t.Title, t.project, t.Problem
    FROM dbo.[table2] t
        JOIN INSERTED I ON t.ID = I.ID
GO
```

If table2 is actually table1 (which makes more sense: how is `table1` related to `storage` and `table2`?)...

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger1 On dbo.[table1] FOR UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO dbo.[storage]
    SELECT Id, Title, project, Problem
    FROM INSERTED
GO
```

Comment: I am having timeout problems with cross server querying. So table 1 is what I'm inputting data into, when the issue_id is entered, I want a trigger to select the data from the other server where it matches the issue id. Then the selected information from the other server will be inserted to a local copy of the other server solving the timeout issues.

Answer (score 2):

Please go through the below suggestion.

Instead of the below line

```
SELECT @Id = Issue_Id FROM dbo.[table1]
```

It had to be following.

```
SELECT Issue_Id FROM Inserted
```

Following is the updated one.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger1
On dbo.[table1] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
Declare @Id int;

With CTE as 
(
    SELECT Issue_Id FROM Inserted I
    Inner Join [table1] T on T.Issue_Id  = I.Issue_Id
)

INSERT INTO dbo.[storage]
SELECT Id, Title, project, Problem
FROM dbo.[table2]
Inner Join CTE c on c.Issue_Id = Id
```

For more information

In SQL server the records which are being inserted / modified or deleted occupies themselves in two temporary tables available in a DML trigger. These tables are INSERTED and DELETED. The INSERTED table has inserted or updated records. The DELETED table has the old state of the records being updated or deleted.

Comment: That still won't work for multi row updates. `dbo.[table2]` would need to `JOIN` onto the `inserted` table rather than assuming `Issue_Id` will just be a single value.

Comment: Yes. Actually @Node17 is inserting record based on particular ID.

Comment: The Issue_ID set will still fail if there multiple rows in 'Inserted'

Comment: You should not create triggers that assume that to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

To handle multple updates and the `inserted` table in one go:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger1
On dbo.[table1] 
FOR UPDATE
AS

INSERT INTO dbo.[storage]
    SELECT Id, Title, project, Problem
    FROM dbo.[table2] t2
         JOIN Inserted i ON i.Issue_ID = t2.Id
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid  joins as it's a cross server query with a major problem with timeouts.

Comment: @NOde17 - cross server query? In a *trigger*? Ewww.

Answer (score 1):

below line should be removed

SELECT @Id = Issue_Id FROM dbo.[table1]

It should be following.

SELECT Issue_Id FROM Inserted